# Possibly redundant tags: chords, chord-theory, and harmony

Tags: discussion, tags

I'd like to open up a discussion on the use of three distinct tags:

- `chords`, currently listed as "Three or more notes sounded together."
- `chord-theory`, currently listed as "For questions about the theory behind building and naming chords."
- And `harmony`, currently listed as "For questions about the 'vertical' aspects of music and how to build and study them."

Can we further clarify the distinction between these three tags, or should they be reduced to just two (or even one)?

Comment: chords and chord-theory may be able to be combined. harmony is definitely a different beast so should be separate :-)

Answer (score 2):

I can see [chord](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chord) and [chord-theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chord-theory) being merged as, although historically [chord](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chord) has been used more to just talk about using or playing a chord while [chord-theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chord-theory) is more in depth talk about how chords are built, named, ect so you wouldn't (or shouldn't) see a question about how to play a chord tagged with [chord-theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chord-theory). If we want to keep the distinction then we should clean up the tag wiki.

The [harmony](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harmony) tag is a separate idea completely. While sometimes chords are used to describe harmony there is much more to it. Harmony is much deeper than just chord and I can pull out many pieces of music where you would never talk about the harmony in terms of chords.

I do admit our tags are not really in a good spot right now and a lot of them need attention. If the consensus is clear on what the community wants I don't mind changing and keeping up with these tags and similar ones as I enjoy the subjects.

Comment: Could I ask for some repertoire that you're thinking of when you say "you would never talk about the harmony in terms of chords"?

Comment: @Richard  anything atonal or microtonal or anything where the harmony is changing very quickly (fugues) or very slowly. More specifically,  _The Unanswered Question_ and _Nocturnes_ while you _can_ reduce to chords, it's not the best representation on what harmonically is happening.